# Как перетащить созданный элемент

Tags: jquery

Вот код создаю элемент с классом но перетаскивание не работает

```
 <html>
<title>GIRD</title>
<SCRIPT src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT>  
$(document).ready(function() {$(".element").draggable({
containment: '#grid',
cursor: 'move',
```

snap: '.element'

```
});}); 
</SCRIPT>

<script type=text/javascript>
function add() {
var d=document.createElement('div');
d.style.width='100px';
d.style.height='150px';
d.className = 'element';
d.style.background='red';
document.body.appendChild(d);
}

</script>

<body>

<style>
#grid {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border: solid 1px grey;
}
.horisontal, .vertical {
    border: solid 1px grey;
position:absolute;
}
.horisontal {
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    position: absolute;    
}
.vertical {
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}

.element{
  width:99px;
    height:99px;
  border: solid 1px black;
   background:green;    
}
#element{
  border: solid 2px black;
   background:red;  
}
</style>

<INPUT onclick="add();return false;" value=Добавить type=button name=Добавить>

<div id="grid"></div>
<div id="total"></div>
<div  class="element"></div>
<div  class="element"></div>

<script type=text/javascript>
var div = document.getElementById('grid');
var gridStep = 20; // Шаг сетки
var gridWidth = 1; // Толщина линии сетки
var width = 660; // Ширина блока
var height = 900; // Высота блока
var div = document.getElementById('grid');
div.style.height = height + 'px';
div.style.width = width + 'px';
var verticalLinesNum = Math.ceil(width / gridStep); 
var horisontalLinesNum = Math.ceil(height / gridStep); 
for (var i = 0; i < horisontalLinesNum / 2; i++) {
    var lines = document.createElement('div');
    lines = div.appendChild(lines);
    lines.className = 'horisontal';
    lines.style.height = (2 * i + 1) * gridStep + 'px';
    lines.style.width = width + 'px';
    lines.style.borderTopWidth = lines.style.borderBottomWidth = gridWidth + 'px';
    lines.style.marginTop = (height - parseInt(lines.style.height)) / 2 + 'px';
    lines.style.overflow = 'hidden';
}
for (var j = 0; j < verticalLinesNum / 2; j++) {
    var lines = document.createElement('div');
    lines = div.appendChild(lines);
    lines.className = 'vertical';
    lines.style.width = (2 * j + 1) * gridStep + 'px';
    lines.style.height = height + 'px';
    lines.style.borderLeftWidth = lines.style.borderRightWidth = gridWidth + 'px';
    lines.style.marginLeft = (width - parseInt(lines.style.width)) / 2 + 'px';
}
var total = document.getElementById('total');
total.innerHTML = 'Создано внутренних блоков: ' + (i + j);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Все из-за того что вы присваиваете свойство draggable в фунции `$(document).ready(function() {`

А это документ уже загружен, а когда добавляете новый никаких перехватов события не делаете, все правильно, что не работает, откуда вашему jq ui знать? =)

Просто добавте функцию что-то типа

```
function setAsDraggable() {
    $(".element").draggable({
        containment: '#grid',
        cursor: 'move'
    });
}
```

и вызывайте ее при загрузке страницы и при создании нового элемента, как-то так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setAsDraggable();
    });

function add() {
  var d=document.createElement('div');
  d.style.width='100px';
  d.style.height='150px';
  d.className = 'element';
  d.style.background='red';
  document.body.appendChild(d);

  // вызов фунции здесь
  setAsDraggable();
}
```

Comment: теперь все ок